# What does "draw" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> 48 min: A long Everton hoof. Calvert-Lewin is the only man up, and he does sensationally well to win an aerial duel with Lindelof, spin him, then run down the left and **draw** a foul from Wan-Bissaka. Free kick to the left of the box.

> GOAL! Everton 1-3 Manchester United (Cavani 90+5)
> It’s four on two. Fernandes down the middle. He **draws** Holgate infield, then plays a cute flick towards Cavani on his left. Cavani nearly runs offside, but he’s OK, and slams into the bottom left!

Comment: [Merriam-Webster's sense 3, d](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/draw)

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "to [draw a foul" mean to play in such a way so that the opposition player fouls you.](https://languagecaster.com/football-language-to-draw-a-foul/#:%7E:text=In%20situations%20like%20these%20players,sees%20this%20as%20a%20foul.)

It can be a valid tactic (you place your body between the player and the ball so that if the opposition player tackles you they are likely to trip you up) or a cheating tactic: making contact and falling over - "diving".

To "draw a player" means to cause a player to run towards you.  So Fernandez ran down the middle of the pitch. Holgate had to run from the wing to mark him. That left space on the left for Cavani.

In both cases the basic meaning of "draw" is "pull".